# docker.sock file exists but unable to run / build / test a docker image (ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon)

Tags: docker, macos

The full error is:
`ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix://Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I'm using a Macbook with M1 Pro chip and macOS Ventura 13.3.1(a). I've tried uninstalling and re-installing docker and verifying that the .sock file exists by using `docker context ls`:

```
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                       KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix://Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock                          
desktop-linux       moby                Docker Desktop                            unix:///Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

I've also tried `ls -lah //Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock`:

```
srwxr-xr-x@ 1 anasputhawala  staff     0B Jul 24 11:32 //Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

so the file definitely does exist.
My zshrc file has this following few lines in it too:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://Users/anasputhawala/.docker/run/docker.sock"
source /Users/anasputhawala/.docker/init-zsh.sh || true # Added by Docker Desktop
```

so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is... If anyone has encountered this please let me know what I can do to fix it and get docker images running etc.

I've tried a few suggestions from other threads, none seem to work. I re-installed docker too.